# Miller's Test Base a

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, mathematica, primality-test, pseudoprimes

Definition - Miller's test base a-

[image]

For the following example, please advise on why Miller's test **passes** according to the output.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $a=2$ test passes because the last table entry is 1 (first statement holds). The $a=3$ test passes because when $r=3$ the second statement holds, that is, the $4$th list element is $267648 = -1 \mod 267649$. When $a=5$, the second statement when $r=4$ holds, that is the $5$th list element is $267648$.